# Suggestion on Creating Unit test for database layer

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

thank you for reading my question.

I was just wondering about how shall i create unit tests for existing database layer. as of now my project has existing unit tests but no unit test is written for database layer or any function which inserts / updates / deletes data from database.

We are using Microsoft tests. One approach I think here is 
1) We shall create database on the fly i.e. mdf file and we will keep our defaults values ready in it and in our setup method(Nunit) or initialize method(MS tests) we will mock the objects and dump the dummy data into tables.

Also we are not using any mocking framework. So i am all confuse.

i need to know how can we do this from the scratch. Also is there anything optional available for mocking framework.

Any pointers or samples would be highly appreciated.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

A C# unit test shall not touch the database, you should mock the database. It should be possible to execute many thousands of unit test on your local machine (without external (internet, databases, other application)) within seconds (and you want to run them when you build your code).

That leaves us kind of with your question unanswered: what should your database layer tests do? It depends on what kind of logic you have in that assembly! If you have "business or decision" logic should should test that, if you have mapping logic test that. If all your database layer does if using (whatever db framework) to put the load on you database then you might not have anything worth testing there.

If you want to test logic performed by your database (say SP's) you should do that in the database project, and most likely not using mstest.

Of course you can use mstest to setup and tear down database and perform test, but those test will not be unit tests.